# When can you upper bound a summation by the Harmonic number?

Tags: inequality, summation, harmonic-numbers

I am currently studying a distributed systems lecture. I came across a relation which I was somewhat confused by.

It states that the following equation

$$ 1+ \sum_{r=2}^n \frac{(n-1)(1)}{(n)(r-1)} $$

is upper bounded ≤ by the harmonic number

$$ 1+H_n=1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i} $$

The reason is that the fraction  $$\frac{(n-1)}{n}$$ is always smaller than 1

Can someone give me more intuition on why does that holds true? Or when can you upper bound a summation by the harmonic number?

Thank you!

Comment: "When can you upper bound a summation by a harmonic number?" is way too broad of a question. As for intuition, well - imagine the summation is adding up a bunch of paychecks you're receiving, but taxes are taken out (that involves multiplying by a positive fraction less than $1$) - isn't it obvious your total income is less than it was before taxes reduced each paycheck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $r\in\{2,3,\ldots,n\}$, then$$\frac{n-1}{n(r-1)}=\frac{n-1}n\times\frac1r<\frac1r$$ and therefore\begin{align}1+\sum_{r=2}^n\frac{n-1}{n(r-1)}&<1+\sum_{r=2}^n\frac1{r-1}\\&=1+\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\frac1r\\&=1+H_{n-1}.\end{align}